# Add values to byte array

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a byte array which contains an image; I converted the image to byte array using this method:

```
public byte[] imageToByteArray(System.Drawing.Image imageIn)
{
 MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
 imageIn.Save(ms,System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Gif);
 return  ms.ToArray();
}
```

This is the byte array:

```
Bitmap bmp =  Image.FromFile("xxx");
byte[] buffer = ImageToByteArray(bmp);
```

Now I would like to add some minor minor information about the image in the byte array,such as the position it should be drawn to,etc.

How could it be done? Lets say i want to add these 2 values:`1209,540`.

Comment: If you want to convert "int" to byte and then append them to the memory stream, you could use the BinaryWriter: writer = new BinaryWriter(ms); writer.Write((int)1209); writer.Write((int)540);

Answer (score 0):

First I don't think you can use these values 1209,540 since byte's max val is 255.

But if your values are between that range 0-255, why don't you add two bytes at the end of the array and when the conversion is to be made remove the last two values?

Comment: would'nt it be posibble to convert these values to byte type?

Comment: @Slashy No, an unsigned can store from 0 to 255. The other way would be to wrap this array in a class where you'd declare another property containing the extra values you'd like to pass!